# journalctl's mmap() calls make it incredibly slow

Tags: performance, mmap

Whenever I run `journalctl`, it runs astonishingly slowly. It often takes minutes or even hours to return results. I've experienced some other performance problems on the affected machine that seemed to be related to I/O-intensive applications; I recently replaced the SATA cable which improved performance but didn't completely fix the problem. I've run S.M.A.R.T. tests on all the drives and they come out okay, based on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes) of "critical" attributes that predict disk failure.

Note that I will not have physical access to the affected machine for several months, unfortunately.

I ran `journalctl -xn` through `strace -T` as root; here's a sampling of the output:

```
fstatfs(23, {f_type=0x9123683e, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=272871862, f_bfree=10246662, f_bavail=9257376, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={-1736151745, 782050752}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 <0.000044>
open("/var/log/journal/40b4c4d188900ed4b228417f53bce3a8/system@000549d205557c7b-3bab3b9a8debeb5c.journal~", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 24 <0.000045>
fstat(24, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=67108864, ...}) = 0 <0.000044>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 24, 0) = 0x7fce771b7000 <0.000052>
mmap(NULL, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 24, 0) = 0x7fce6be4c000 <0.000101>
fstatfs(24, {f_type=0x9123683e, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=272871862, f_bfree=10246681, f_bavail=9257367, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={-1736151745, 782050752}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 <0.000044>
open("/var/log/journal/40b4c4d188900ed4b228417f53bce3a8/system@000549e2c7cdcf84-9d1738f7aa7e2bbb.journal~", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 25 <0.000040>
fstat(25, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=83886080, ...}) = 0 <0.000040>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 25, 0) = 0x7fce771b6000 <0.000177>
mmap(NULL, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 25, 0) = 0x7fce6b64c000 <0.000126>
fstatfs(25, {f_type=0x9123683e, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=272871862, f_bfree=10246807, f_bavail=9257509, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={-1736151745, 782050752}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 <0.000071>
open("/var/log/journal/40b4c4d188900ed4b228417f53bce3a8/system@00054a0d278bd396-a5f78900d1a76e3a.journal~", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 26 <0.000073>
fstat(26, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=67108864, ...}) = 0 <0.000046>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 26, 0) = 0x7fce771b5000 <0.554027>
mmap(NULL, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 26, 0) = 0x7fce6ae4c000 <0.000155>
fstatfs(26, {f_type=0x9123683e, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=272871862, f_bfree=10248655, f_bavail=9257373, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={-1736151745, 782050752}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 <0.000091>
open("/var/log/journal/40b4c4d188900ed4b228417f53bce3a8/user-5000@00054a0d2867ce5c-2c11c922477ad87d.journal~", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 27 <0.000082>
fstat(27, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=8388608, ...}) = 0 <0.000064>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 27, 0) = 0x7fce771b4000 <0.129685>
mmap(NULL, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 27, 0) = 0x7fce6a64c000 <0.000119>
fstatfs(27, {f_type=0x9123683e, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=272871862, f_bfree=10245778, f_bavail=9256592, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={-1736151745, 782050752}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 <0.000043>
open("/var/log/journal/40b4c4d188900ed4b228417f53bce3a8/system@00054a203119342d-9cc91adca322dda0.journal~", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 28 <0.000043>
fstat(28, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=109051904, ...}) = 0 <0.000047>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 28, 0) = 0x7fce771b3000 <2.106414>
mmap(NULL, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 28, 0) = 0x7fce69e4c000 <0.000099>
fstatfs(28, {f_type=0x9123683e, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=272871862, f_bfree=10247093, f_bavail=9257207, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={-1736151745, 782050752}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 <0.000037>
open("/var/log/journal/40b4c4d188900ed4b228417f53bce3a8/system@00054a25abc23b2b-87a21b1480ce83fc.journal~", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 29 <0.000039>
fstat(29, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=50331648, ...}) = 0 <0.000034>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 29, 0) = 0x7fce771b2000 <0.000043>
mmap(NULL, 8388608, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 29, 0) = 0x7fce6964c000 <0.000026>
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC) = 30 <0.000019>
read(30, "_\f\327\367\310\220\344\23U\307\23N@\310\323\226", 16) = 16 <0.000010>
close(30)                               = 0 <0.000010>
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC) = 30 <0.000014>
read(30, "u\207\326\2360t\0T*\34\222\226\4\22\361w", 16) = 16 <0.000011>
close(30)                               = 0 <0.000010>
fstatfs(29, {f_type=0x9123683e, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=272871862, f_bfree=10246938, f_bavail=9257024, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={-1736151745, 782050752}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0 <0.000015>
open("/var/log/journal/40b4c4d188900ed4b228417f53bce3a8/system@00054a300132019a-2f63039e261fecd4.journal~", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 30 <0.000014>
fstat(30, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=58720256, ...}) = 0 <0.000010>
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 30, 0) = 0x7fce771b1000 <3.332606>
```

The process always seems to hang for a while on `mmap()` calls that look similar to the last one. I used `dd if=/dev/zero of=testfile.tmp` to benchmark disk I/O. When doing this I observed disk write hovering around 1000 M/s (+/- ~150 M/s most of the time), although it occasionally dropped down to 300 M/s or lower (going all the way down to ~70 M/s). When I killed it `dd` reported `15689293824 bytes (16 GB) copied, 174.361 s, 90.0 MB/s`. Tellingly, when running the same test backwards (`dd if=testfile.tmp of=/dev/null`), the disk read performance as reported by `iotop` didn't get above 250 M/s, was almost always below 100 M/s, and was often below 50 M/s. Killing this second `dd` process produced `10573660160 bytes (11 GB) copied, 148.573 s, 71.2 MB/s`.

Here's some more debugging information (note that these were run *after* I killed the `journalctl -xn` process):

```
% find /var/log/journal | wc -l
115
% uname -a
Linux steevie 4.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2~bpo8+1 (2017-01-05) x86_64 GNU/Linux
% vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0 1495592 160420     80 4586516  199  179 15827  1391   15    8  7  5 37 51  0
```

Note that the filesystem is on a btrfs RAID1 array and one of the devices is inside a LUKS container (for historical reasons):

```
% sudo btrfs filesystem show /
Label: '[root]'  uuid: 06c6565d-af6c-4123-9e42-3b6281f164e6
        Total devices 4 FS bytes used 990.93GiB
        devid    2 size 931.47GiB used 931.47GiB path /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt
        devid    4 size 109.45GiB used 109.45GiB path /dev/sda6
        devid    5 size 109.45GiB used 109.45GiB path /dev/sdb6
        devid    6 size 931.47GiB used 931.47GiB path /dev/sdc2

% sudo btrfs device usage /
/dev/mapper/sda2_crypt, ID: 2
   Device size:           931.47GiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,RAID1:            917.50GiB
   Metadata,RAID1:         13.94GiB
   System,RAID1:           32.00MiB
   Unallocated:             1.02MiB

/dev/sda6, ID: 4
   Device size:           109.45GiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,RAID1:            102.51GiB
   Metadata,RAID1:          6.94GiB
   Unallocated:             1.00MiB

/dev/sdb6, ID: 5
   Device size:           109.45GiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,RAID1:            104.42GiB
   Metadata,RAID1:          5.00GiB
   System,RAID1:           32.00MiB
   Unallocated:             3.00MiB

/dev/sdc2, ID: 6
   Device size:           931.47GiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,RAID1:            927.47GiB
   Metadata,RAID1:          4.00GiB
   Unallocated:             1.02MiB
```

`sda2_crypt` here is misleading; it's actually backed by `/dev/sdd2`. `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are SSDs; `/dev/sdc` and `/dev/sdd` are HDDs.

I'm on Debian 8. Happy to post `smartctl` logs if needed, but they're kinda long which is why I'm omitting them at this point.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `mmap()` that's slow?  It could also be the `open()` calls, or something else entirely.  You can add options such as `-t`/`-tt`/`-ttt` and/or `-T` to get timing data.  Your disk IO rates from `dd` don't account for things like opening files.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yeah, I watched the output in realtime and it was clearly paused on `mmap()`. if timing information would be helpful beyond that though, I'm happy to provide it.

Comment: Did the pause happen *after* it emitted the `mmap()` lines?  If so, `mmap()` has already returned - note that there's a return value on all your `mmap()` lines.

Comment: @AndrewHenle ooo, nice catch. I'll edit the question to correct that.